# Is this pattern considered idiomatic for declaring class options?

Tags: ruby

Is this pattern OK for declaring class level options? What is `Options` considered here? A class (class names start with a capital letter)? A constant? A normal variable inside the class?

```
class Markdown
  Options = {
    no_intra_emphasis: true,
    fenced_code_blocks: true,
    strikethrough: true
  }

  def initialize(text, options = {})
    @text = text
    @options = options.reverse_merge!(Options)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you ok that people can change your `Options`: `Markdown::Options=42` and `Markdown::Options[:no_intra_emphasis]=42`? ps. only first snippet raise a warning!

Comment: @DarekNędza if someone can change `Markdown::Options[:no_intra_emphasis]=42` they can also pass in an options hash to the `initialize` method. So they have no motive to tamper with the `Options` the way you show, right?

Comment: Well, you don't know evil/*stupid* user. My point is that `Options` can be changed by anyone, anywhere, sometimes you won't even know that. You may think that `m1 = Markdown.new "a"` defined in the line 1 is *equal* `m2 = Markdown.new "a"` defined in the line 45 but on the line 42 someone modified part of your `Options` making this 2 variables not equal.

Comment: @DarekNędza I see. I think that is easily avoided by calling `freeze` on the hash, no?

Comment: Don't trust `freeze` too much. As for Hash, ruby freeze *pointers*, so as for this hash: `h={a: 2, b: [1,2,3], c: 'string'}` you cannot assign new value to `h`( `h = 42` ), nor assign new values to keys( `h[:a] = 42`) but you can modify array( `h[:b][1] = 42` ) and you can modify in place strings( `h[:c].gsub("i", "*")` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it is usual or unusual does not matter. It is valid, and can be useful. It is a constant referring to a hash, not a class, nor a variable.

It is not that particularly a class name starts with a capital letter. A constant starts with a capital letter, of which a class name is a special case. But a capital does not necessarily mean a constant. Method names may or may not start with a capital.

Answer (score 2):

As `Options` is a constant, I would rather use a name like `OPTIONS`, which is closer to Ruby convention (you can see that id uses names like `File::Constants::APPEND`, in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File/Constants.html). The way it is written now, it makes me think of a class rather than a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell what it's doing and why within a few seconds of looking at it? If so, it communicates its point effectively, even if it is somewhat non-idiomatic. In this case, it looks like it defines some default values for `@options`, so it looks good to me - unless it does something else in the context of your overall program, in which case it's confusing because it does something besides what it looks like it's doing.

Also, `Options` is capitalized to indicate that should be treated as a constant and ideally shouldn't be changed at runtime. That's also why class names are usually capitalized: they are usually constants. (Ruby doesn't actually enforce this. It's a convention used to make it easier to tell what values shouldn't be changed without deliberately using metaprogramming techniques.)

Comment: So what is the idiomatic way of declaring options?

Comment: I'm not sure there is one. I think that merging a default options hash is the most common way, so this is actually pretty idiomatic.

Comment: @Kevin Taro's deleted comment, as well as you stating it correct, is wrong. A token starting with a capital may or may not be a constant.

Comment: True, but it's idiomatic to use capitalized identifiers to communicate that a value should be treated as a constant.

Comment: @Kevin As for Ruby 2 or later there exist *named parameters*.

Comment: Yes, but named parameters won't help for setting the default values inside of a hash. That is, if one of my parameters to a function is a hash and I want the hash to have some default values, then using a defaults hash is one of the easiest ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) library does this too; the constant is called DEFAULT_OPTIONS there.